Can someone aid me by revealing the translation of this script
I thought that if I included all characters, it might make it easier for the viewers to give the translation. (Please see image).

時雨初(?)晴
慕末(來?)元東(?)
用墨等(?)於(?)
岡州苗(面?)來(?)
折指熊楠

Looks like 時雨初晴 for me

You are right,and make it sense

柳橋熊楠

Thanks to everyone but special thanks to Tang Ho. This appears to be a more likely translation because it seems to be referring to the artist Baishi, who is the artist that did this painting.
